# Create an array from dynamic number of widgets with Jinja (Hubspot HubL)

Tags: python, jinja2, hubspot

I am using HubL which is Hubspots limited version of Jinja. Server side coding in python or php is not an option in Hubspot, just fyi.

I am using a Choice and Loop to allow the person editing to page to choose the number of background images they would like to make available to the page.

```
{% set bg_num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] %}

{% choice "bg_num_choice" label="Number of Background Images", value="3", choices="{{ bg_num }}", export_to_template_context=True %}

{% for options in bg_num %}

     {% if loop.index <= widget_data.bg_num_choice.value %}

         {% image_src "bg_img" label="Background Image", unique_in_loop=True, export_to_template_context=True %}

     {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, based on the number chosen this will enable that many Image src modules on the page.

The issue that I am having is that I now need to choose one of these at random (each time the page loads) and assign it to the div:

```
<div class="home_body_wrapper" style="background: url({{ Assign Here }});"> </div>
```

To do this I know that I need to collect the src values of the modules that are created into an array, then use the random filter to print the value where I need it.

The problem is that I have to create the array dynamically. I cannot set the array values static because I would either have empty values or have to change the array based on how many images are used.

How can I dynamically add these modules' values to an array?